# Play2 Java + Heroku Application - Cache Usage

Tags: java, caching, heroku, playframework-2.0

Play2 framework provide us ability to use cache https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache.

However, I have few question as I am not sure how to use it smartly.

What is the size of the cache? It depends on my Heroku Cloud plan or size of cache is default for play?

Are there any best practices? Assuming I have 200 objects with 10 fields, is it smart to store them in cache or cache is primarly used for one object?

If I have 10 users accessing my application and If I store user objects in cache, what is the best logic behind to differentiate caches for every user? For example, I do not want UserX to access UserY cache...

Answer (score 0):

Play default implementation of the cache API uses [EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/). which is an in- memory cache. So the size depends on you, you can configure it by providing an ehcache.xml file with the relevant configuration.

Configure it based on your use case, and the memory that is available for you on the dyno you own.

Regards the way you store objects in cache, there are many approaches and it really depends.
In case of users, I would use a user unique id (id \ email \ other) as the key, you just need to make sure each user will try to fetch the stored information by providing it's unique id.